# Yii1: Save each records into database

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

Currently, I could not be able to save each record which is generated by SQL. Since I am only able to save the last record of the generated list.

This is my code.

```
$db = Yii::app ()->db;
$sql = 'SELECT  "product", "type", "retailerId", SUM("total") AS "total" 
                                                        FROM "Sales" 
                                                        GROUP BY K."product", C."type", K."retailerId" ';

$rs = $db->createCommand ( $sql )->query ();
while ( $_o1 = $rs->read () ) {

    $_col_no = null;

    switch ( $_o1['product'] ) {
        case 1:
            $_col_no = 'D';
            break;

        case 3:
            $_col_no = 'G';
            break;

        default:
            switch ( $_o1['type'] ) {
                case 'A':
                    $_col_no = 'F';
                    break;

                case '2':
                    $_col_no = 'E';
                    break;

                case '3':
                    $_col_no = 'H';
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }

    if ( !$_col_no ) {
        continue;
    }
    $data[$_col_no]['agent'][$_o1['retailerId']] = $_o1['total'];
    $data[$_col_no]['total'] += $_o1['total'];
}
foreach ( $data as $_col1 => $_info1 ) {
    foreach ( $_info1['agent'] as $_index => $_value ) {
        if ( !$o = self::model ()->findByAttributes ( array(
            'Code' => $code ,
            'retailerId' => $o_retailerId ,
                ) ) ) {

            $o = new self();

            $o->id = Utils::getUniqId ();
            $o->retailerId = $_index;  //have to save every retailerId
            $o->Code = 0;
            ///$o->total = have to save total relavant to each retailer                     
        }
    }
}

if ( !$o->save () ) {
    $_errors = current ( $o->getErrors () );
    throw new Exception ( $_errors[0] );
}
```

So here When I print the `$list` it is given all retailerIds. But I don't know how to save each records under unique `$o->id`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, it will save the last record only because you are calling save outside the `foreach` loop. You need to move it inside so that `save()` is called for every iteration.

So move this part of code

```
if ( !$o->save () ) {
    $_errors = current ( $o->getErrors () );
    throw new Exception ( $_errors[0] );
}
```

inside the nested `foreach`

```
foreach ( $data as $_col1 => $_info1 ) {
    foreach ( $_info1['agent'] as $_index => $_value ) {
        if ( !$o = self::model ()->findByAttributes ( array(
            'Code' => $code ,
            'retailerId' => $o_retailerId ,
                ) ) ) {

            $o = new self();

            $o->id = Utils::getUniqId ();
            $o->retailerId = $_index;  //have to save every retailerId
            $o->Code = 0;
            ///$o->total = have to save total relavant to each retailer 

           //call save here to save the current record  
           if ( !$o->save () ) {
              $_errors = current ( $o->getErrors () );
              throw new Exception ( $_errors[0] );
           }                  
        }
    }
}
```